# Python pylab: Making a plot with adjusted spines, but doesn't plot

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot

I've read through a bunch of documentation on pylab and pyplot, and some past posts on stackoverflow, but I just can't get this to work the way I'd expect it to.  I'm trying to create a simple plotting function by the following code:

```
import numpy as np
import pylab as pl

def simplePlot(xStart, xStop, f):
    x = np.linspace(xStart, xStop, num=(xStart-xStop)*100)
    y = [f(i) for i in x]

    pylab.figure()
    ax = plt.gca()
    pylab.plot(x,y)
    ax.xaxis.set_ticks_position('bottom')
    ax.yaxis.set_ticks_position('left')
    ax.spines['left'].set_position(('data', 0))
    ax.spines['bottom'].set_position(('data', 0))
    pylab.show()

def funct(x):
    return x**2 - x

simplePlot(-2,2,funct)
```

I was thinking this should bring up a graph from -2 to 2 on the x-axis, with the axis spines running through the center of the figure, of the function f(x) = x^2-x.  Instead, it produces a figure that's blank except that the spines run through the center and go from -0.6 to 0.6.

If possible, it'd be nice to both have an explanation of why this code is producing its result so that I better understand what these commands are doing, as well as code that will do what I want.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is where you define x:

```
x = np.linspace(xStart, xStop, num=(xStart-xStop)*100)
```

`xStart` is less than `xStop` so you're asking for a negative number of points, in which case numpy gives you a zero-length array. So your plot is a perfectly accurate plot of two zero-length arrays against each other! If you change it to:

```
x = np.linspace(xStart, xStop, num=(xStop-xStart)*100)
```

then you'll get what you expected.